# Show geometry column on attribute table in QGIS from Geopackage

Tags: qgis-3, geopackage, gui

Id would like the ability to show the geometry column on the attribute table in QGIS, when the data source is a Geopackage.

The context is that, im going to be entering geometry-less records as placeholders and need other more 'basic' users be able to sort them later on to identify the records that do not have a geometry 'value' populated, and add it in. The attribute table is the current 'working location' where they edit/modify data, so ideally would like the solution exposed there.

Currently, this is a capability that is available in the DB Manager, when selecting a table in a GeoPackage, the geometry column is listed, showing the WKT definition of the geometry. This is ideal in how it looks, however it is in the DB Manager GUI, not the standard attribute table GUI and as such is not a suitable solution.

I have a work-around, which is to create a new calculated field or similar and use the expression below to expose it as a new column.

```
 geom_to_wkt( $geometry)
```

However, what I would like to know specifically, is if there is an Out Of Box facility available that does this already?

Is there an option or check box/setting somewhere, that can enable this column to be shown by default, for all tables across the QGIS Project?

Using QGIS 3.22.7 and Geopackage data sources.

Comment: By "*create a new calculated field*" do you mean create a virtual field in the field calculator?

Comment: I am not aware of such option. You can try the somewhat simpler `$geometry is not null` expression, especially if you have heavy geometries

Comment: @JGH Yes this might be an alternative as well, ill need to work if the end users need to know the geometry type (multipoly) that is returned by the WKT statement.

Comment: @user2856 hey, I wasn't thinking of a virtual field no -  the data will need to be persistent in future sessions. The idea was to simply add a new field based on an expression in the Field Calculator tool.